# Mapping DTO to Entity while TrackingChanges with AutoMapper and EFCore

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, automapper

Very new to AutoMapper and EFCore, so maybe biting off more than i can chew here, but thought i would give it a go, but failing, and maybe it aint possible, but if it is maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

I am using AutoMapper to convert my entities to a DTO, this is fine.

Now i would like to convert my DTO to an entity and have EntityFramework track all the changes (property updated, child object removed from list etc), but is this possible?

So if i have a simple PUT method, i would like to do something like this, and let automapper sort out the rest

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PutAsync([FromBody] MyDTO model)
{
    // GET OBJECT FROM DATABASE HERE
    var dbValue = _repos.GetMyObjectUsingId(999);

    // apply updates
    _mapper.Map<MyDTO, MyObject>(dbValue, model);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an adapter class so your change set remains the same:
Have you DTO's inherit from an interface

Say you have a DTO:

```
public interface IFooDTO
{
   int Id { get; set;}
   string Name { get; set;}
}

public class FooDTO : IFooDTO
{
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have your entity

```
public class FooEntity
{
   public int Id;
   public string name;
}
```

Then create your adapter like so which inherits from the foo interface:

```
public class FooAdapter : IFooDTO
{
   FooEntity entity;
   FooAdapter(FooEntity entity)
   {
      this.entity = entity;
   }

   public int Id 
   {
      get {return this.entity.Id;}
      set {/*Do nothing set by EF*/}
   }

   public string Name
   {
       get {return this.entity.Name;}
       set {this.entity.Name = value; }
   }

   public void Apply(FooDTO foo)
   {
        //I don't remember if this is the correct order but you get the gyst
        this._mapper.Map<IFooDTO, IFooDTO>(this, foo);
   }
}
```

Then you just need to Map from your Idto to you dto in the mapper.

Usage:

```
 public ActionResult PutFoo(int id, FooDTO foo)
 {
     var entity = context.Foos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
     var adapter = new FooAdapter(entity);
     adapter.Apply(foo);
     //Entity has been updated and has original changes
 }
```

**EDIT**

Children Work fine just use the same adapter pattern the setter for this is a lot of code but

```
public BarDTO childBar
{
   get { return new BarAdapter(this.entity.Bar).ToDTO(); }
   set { new BarAdapter(this.entity.Bar).Apply(value) }
}
```

Syncing Entities:

```
public static void Sync<TEntity, TEntityKey, TDTO>(this ICollection<TEntity> entityCollection, ICollection<TDTO> dtoCollection,
    Func<TEntity> entityConstructor, Action<TDTO, TEntity> copyAction,
    Action<TEntity> onDeleteAction,
    Func<TEntity, TEntityKey> entityKeySelector, 
    Func<TDTO, TEntityKey> dtoKeySelector)
    where TEntity : class
    where TEntityKey : struct
{
    dtoCollection = dtoCollection ?? new TDTO[] { };
    except = except ?? new TEntityKey[] { };

    var dtoIds = dtoCollection.Select(dto => dtoKeySelector(dto)).ToHashSet();
    foreach (var entity in entityCollection.Where(x => false == dtoIds.Contains(entityKeySelector(x))).ToArray())
    {
        onDeleteAction(entity);
        entityCollection.Remove(entity);
    }

    var entityCollectionMap = entityCollection.ToDictionary(x => entityKeySelector(x));

    foreach (var dtoItem in dtoCollection)
    {
        TEntity entity = null;
        if (dtoKeySelector(dtoItem).HasValue)
        {
            entity = entityCollectionMap.ContainsKey(dtoKeySelector(dtoItem)) ? entityCollectionMap[dtoKeySelector(dtoItem)] : default(TEntity);

        }

        if (null == entity)
        {
            entity = entityConstructor();
            entityCollection.Add(entity);
        }
        copyAction(dtoItem, entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is very interesting... thank you.  Can you also make this work for child objects and lists within the object??  in lists, will automapper, remove the item from a list if it is not in the DTO (matching on ID)??

Comment: @user2736022 i'm glad this answer can be useful, I've updated the answer for child object, hopefully this satisfys your Original Post.  You can have a global sync method to do what you stated above Just union and update the ICollection that just a lot of extra code to figure out,  If I have time late I'll put in another update

Comment: The getter is easy though `get { return this.entity.Bars.Select(b => new BarAdapter(b).ToDTO()).ToList();  }`

Comment: would really appreciate it if you could let me know about collection.... Thanks again!

Comment: @user2736022 That's should be the pseudo sync code give or take you have to play with it.  if this should satisfy your original question, please mark as answer and vote

Comment: use would look something like this, I'm using modified context with extensions etc. but you'll figure out how to implement `this.entity.Bars.Sync(value, () => new Bar(), (source, target) => { source.Apply(new BarAdapter(target)); }, e.SetDeleted )`